# WCF mex does not contain the complete binding information from the host

Tags: wcf, binding, mex

I'm publishing a service with a MEX endpoint for metadata exchange and I'm using the code below to discover it and get the metadata information

```
DiscoveryClient discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
FindCriteria findCriteria =      FindCriteria.CreateMetadataExchangeEndpointCriteria(ContractType);
findCriteria.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
findCriteria.MaxResults = 1;// MaxResults;

FindResponse result = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);
discoveryClient.Close();

ServiceEndpointCollection eps = MetadataResolver.Resolve(ContractType, result.Endpoints[0].Address);
return eps[0].Binding;
```

When I get the metadata information in my client the binding information (`OpenTimeout`,
`ReceiveTimeout` and  `SendTimeout`) is back to its default values.

Here is the binding information in the host

```
<binding name="MyServiceBinding" closeTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00"
      receiveTimeout="23:50:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000">
   <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="50000000" maxArrayLength="50000000" />
   <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:01:00" enabled="false" />
   <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

here is another question i've found that is almost the same as mine.

[WCF Service Binding taking default values instead of custom values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056675/wcf-service-binding-taking-default-values-instead-of-custom-values)

I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if I misunderstood the concept of metadata exchange.

What I'm trying to do is send all the info necessary to my clients so they can auto config them self  and do not have any hard code configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong - you're just expecting too much from the metadata exchange.

The purpose of MEX is to be able to discover new services programmatically, and create client-side proxies for those services. For this, there's the WSDL - basically anything contained in the WSDL is part of the metadata exchange:

- service contract / service methods
- parameters needed for those service methods
- data type declarations in XML schema for the data types used
- additional service related information like bindings used etc.

But MEX does **not** contain all WCF specific configuration settings - which is what you've discovered. MEX will create a functioning client-side proxy - but it never had the intention of transporting all configuration settings from the server to the client. You'll need to hand-code this yourself, on the client side.

Comment: then should I use WSDL instead?

Comment: @Jose Manuel Ojeda: no, that won't make any difference; MEX and WSDL are pretty much the same. There just isn't any way to automatically exchange config information like timeouts through MEX or WSDL.

Comment: I just faced this problem when trying to modify maxMessageLenght. If you can't publish full binding informations, this makes this whole mex publishing useless as you still have to have some configuration information on the client side...