# Visual Studio "Add Service Reference" - not gets all service settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, binding, client, wcf-binding

my purpose is to ensure that - when someone clicks on "Add Service Reference" in his own Visual Studio, and he adds references to my WCF service - he receives not the default settings, but the settings of the service.

In particular, there is a property of the "binding" class that interests me: useDefaultWebProxy, I need it setted to "false".

I tried this, but with no results:
In the Web.config file of the service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0" ... useDefaultWebProxy="false">
     <readerQuotas ... />
    </binding>
   </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="pippo.pluto">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
             bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="pluto" contract="pippo.ipluto" />
    <host>
     <timeouts ... />
    </host>
   </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
     <serviceMetadata ... />
     <serviceDebug ... />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Nothing to do: in the client's Web.config I always get...

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="pluto" ... useDefaultWebProxy="true">
   <readerQuotas ... />
   <security ...>
    <transport ... />
    <message ... />
   </security>
  </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

It seems that the bindingConfiguration of the service is completely ignored, not only useDefaultWebProxy but also other properties - for example maxBufferSize - maintain the default values (65536)

How can I do?
Pileggi

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Service Binding taking default values instead of custom values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056675/wcf-service-binding-taking-default-values-instead-of-custom-values)